# How to concatenate two Boolean values with OGNL in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I have two variables set like this:

```
<s:set var="A" value="true" />
<s:set var="B" value="false" />
```

I want to generate the HTML below with a custom attribute `info` like this :

```
<td info="truefalse">&#160;</td>
```

I tried the following lines in my JSP file but I can't get `true` next to `false`:

```
<td info="<s:property value="#A?'true':'false'+#B?'true':'false'""/>&#160;</td>
```

outputs: `<td info="true">&#160;</td>`

```
<td info="<s:property value="#A" /><s:property value="#B" />">&#160;</td>
```

outputs: `<td info="false">&#160;</td>`

Comment: The first one won't work because you have syntax errors. The second one should work.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have updated my question with the outputs of the solution I tried

Comment: The first one won't generate that kind of output, because it throws an exception.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the missing `/>` is in the posted code only. BTW Stephan, why are you messing with this kind of things ? Which is the larger picture, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: And `td` doesn't have `info` attribute.

Comment: Looking at the answers IMO this is better suited in code golf site. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OGNL uses `+` to concatenate strings. Having boolean values to convert to string, you should do something like

```
<s:property value="%{''+#A+#B}"/>
```

Comment: Is it possible to view the `trace evaluation` of ognl used by Struts ?

Comment: It would be good if you ask this in another question with explanation why do you need it.

Comment: Please find my question related to `trace evaluations` here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078472/363573

Answer (score 1):

Use `<s:if>` Try this

```
<s:set var="A" value="true" />
<s:set var="B" value="false" />

<td info="<s:if test="%{#A==true}">true</s:if><s:else>false</s:else><s:if test="%{#B==true}">true</s:if><s:else>false</s:else>">&#160;</td>
 OR
<td info="<s:property value="#A" /><s:property value="#B" />">&#160;</td>
```

**outputs:**

```
<td info="truefalse">&#160;</td>
```

**Reason:** You can not concatenate `Boolean`. You need to convert `Boolean` to `string` and you can concatenate `strings` only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this might help you..

`<td info="<s:property value="A"></s:property><s:property value="B"></s:property>">&#160;</td>`

Comment: I tried and I get this output: `<td info="false">&#160;</td>`

Comment: This link can be useful for you  http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/struts-user/200711.mbox/%3C4740E6CF.604@pussep.de%3E